# Limit of integral with gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

By some relations of Whittaker functions and a comment I read in a paper I came up with the following identity
$$\lim_{s\to 0+} \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-vt} t^{s-1} (1+t)^{s+1}dt =1,$$
which should hold for all positive $v$ (the $0+$ under the limit shall indicate that I approch $s=0$ with positive values of $s$ since that are the values for which the expression is defined). Is there a direct way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts with $u=e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}$ and $v=t^s/s$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-vt}t^{s-1}(1+t)^{s+1}\,dt&=\left.\left(\frac{t^s}{s}e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\right|_0^\infty -\frac1s \int_0^\infty t^s\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac1s \int_0^\infty t^s\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\,dt
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\Gamma(s)\sim \frac1s$ as $s\to 0^+$, the limit of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty e^{-vt}t^{s-1}(1+t)^{s+1}\,dt&=-\lim_{s\to 0^+}\int_0^\infty t^s\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=-\lim_{s\to 0^+}\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=-\lim_{s\to 0^+}\left.\left((e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\right|_0^\infty\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. How do you formally reason to replace $t^s$ by $1$ in the third from last equality?  Is this some sort of dominated convergence?

Comment: Yes, the DCT or UC works.

Comment: Would you mind making this more explicit?

Comment: Fix $v>0$.  For $s\in [0,1]$ we see that for $t>1$$$\left| t^s \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-vt}(1+t)^{s+1}\right)\right|\le t e^{-vt}(v(1+t)^2+2(1+t))$$

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Hi. I hope you're doing well. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm fine. So considering your estimate: That's somehow what I would have done as well. I was wondering if you could do it without actually computing the derivative, that's why I asked. For $t\in[0,1]$ I guess you argue that it's the continuous image of something compact and therefore bounded. One remark to your $\Gamma(s)\sim \frac1s$ argument. Alternatively, you could simply use the functional equation of the gamma function and get $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)}$.
By the way: I was the one giving you an upvote right away and now you get your deserved acceptance. Thx a lot!

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Pleased to hear that you're doing well.  And you're certainly welcome!  My pleasure.